# Tivoli Logfile Monitoring - Regex to exclude

Tags: tivoli

I am sorry if it is not right to post a question on two forums.

We use **Tivoli** to monitor our logs files. The `log4j` log level is set to `ERROR` and Tivoli would raise tickets for these statements. But there are some known issues for which we would **not** want Tivoli to raise tickets. Is there a way to specify that some statements need to be ignored ?

Current regex : `[/var/tmp/abc.log;ERROR(.*);error found: RegExp1]`

This is very generic. We need to exclude certain framework errors (Hibernate / Mule) for a known issue. Is there a way to specify using a regex ?

Thanks,
Midhun

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the LO Agent you can configure situation formula based on regular expression to fit your needs.

Below the LO Agent User Guide
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v15r1/topic/com.ibm.itm.doc_6.2.3fp1/logfileagent623fp2_user.pdf

Take a look at the "Log File RegEx Statistics attribute group" section:

> The Log File RegEx Statistics attribute group contains information that shows the statistics of the log file
>   regular expression search expressions. Regular expressions can be used to filter records or to define
>   records. This attribute group shows information about both types. When the Result Type attribute value
>   is INCLUDE or EXCLUDE, the filter is used to filter records;

Hope this helps

I don't have the reputation yet to post a comment but I'd have liked to ask if you are using the Tivoli Log File Agent (lo) of the Unix Log Agent (ul) before answering.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is still actual...
Here is documentationof LogAgent - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4EKN_7.2.0.2/com.ibm.itm.doc_6.3/logfile/klo_fileformat_specs.htm

You can specify new Regex as DISCARDED and all records mathced this regex will be not catched by ITM Events.

> If you use the special predefined event class *DISCARD* as your event class, any log records matching the associated pattern are discarded, and no events are generated for them. For example:
>   REGEX *DISCARD*
>   As a pattern matched, nothing is written to the unmatch log. The log file status records matched include these discarded events.

Answer (score 0):

BTW

```
[/var/tmp/abc.log;ERROR(.*);error found: RegExp1]
```

may be better as

```
[/var/tmp/abc.log;ERROR([^;]*);error found: RegExp1]
```

.* is greedy and best avoided when possible